# eth_getLogs compared to eth.getPastLogs

Tags: ethereum, web3js

Is using `eth_getLogs` the same as `eth.getPastLogs` in the `web3js` library?
Wondering what the difference is and when should they be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are the same. The function `getPastLogs()` [internally just calls `getLogs()`](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/7c13a90e6a1bdffbcce8f9a2dc0d2272b9be5e4e/packages/web3-eth/src/web3_eth.ts#L1221) (with one default return type).